# Django ValueError: The view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django

My problem is that in the templates and in the CMD I return `None` instead of the images.

The views:

```py
class AddProductImages(TemplateView):
    template_name = "addimages.html"
    
    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            images = self.request.FILES.getlist('images')
            product = Product.objcts.get(id = self.kwargs['pk'])
    
            for image in images:
                product_images = Images.objcts.create(
                    product = product,
                    images = image
                )

            return redirect('index')
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

The urls:

```py
path('addimages/<int:pk>/', AddProductImages.as_view(), name="addimages"),
```

The templates:

```html
<div class="container my-5">
  <br />
  <h1>ADD IMAGE</h1>
  <br />
  <hr />
  <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="images" id="" class="form-control" multiple>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary my-3">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

The results:

> ValueError: The view photo.views.AddProductImages didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
> [31/Aug/2022 22:08:11] "POST /addimages/1/ HTTP/1.1" 500 65400

So, could someone check this please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is important to return a HttpResponse object. Here's how to correct it -

1. When you catch the exception, you still have to return an HTTPResponse object. In the absence of a return statement, it will error out with the message you are currently receiving.
2. To resolve #1, I have added another redirect statement in the exception block. Please add a target that works in your case.
3. There is a typo when you are creating an `Image`. It should be `Images.objects.create`. The typo is currently on the word `object`. Because it was erroring out, the flow was hitting the exception block and subsequently breaking your flow.

```
class AddProductImages(TemplateView):
    template_name = "addimages.html"

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            images = self.request.FILES.getlist('images')
            product = Product.objects.get(id = self.kwargs['pk'])

            for image in images:
                product_images = Images.objects.create(
                        product = product,
                        images = image

                    )
            return redirect('index')
        except Exception as e:
            return redirect('some_other_target')
```

Answer (score 0):

It likely excepted since thats the only place you aren't returning anything.

I can also see why it's excepting.

```
product_images = Images.objcts.create(
                        product = product,
                        images = image

                    )
```

should be:

```
product_images = Images.objects.create(
                        product = product,
                        images = image

                    )
```

Hey, at least now you found out why a blanket `except` statement like this, is not good. Try to be more specific with exceptions. You could even do:

```
try:
    code...
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)
except Product.DoesNotExist as e:
    print(e)
```

This way you can tailor your code to the exceptions raised, and a simple `SyntaxError` won't catch you off-guard like this.